# Problem On Subsets

Tags: geometry, elementary-set-theory

The following is a textbook question that stumped me as there is no more information given.
Is this statement true or false?

> $\{ x : x \text{ is a triangle in a plane} \}$ is a subset of $\{ x : x\text{ is a rectangle in the plane} \}$.

Comment: Tricky question ! Because a rectangle with one side zero can be a triangle !

Answer (score 3):

This is false.  Since rectangles are not triangles and triangles are not rectangles, the two sets are disjoint and therefore neither set is a subset of the other.

Answer (score 3):

False.

Can you think of a triangle that's not a rectangle?

Comment: I think, you should write "Can you think of a triangle that's  a rectangle?"

Comment: @SakshamSharma i don't think so; only one counterexample need exist for the conclusion to be false

Answer (score -1):

Its true because two triangles combine to form a rectangle. So the set of rectangle would contain two triangles. And therefore a triangle is a subset of a rectangle.

Comment: In general, $x, y \in X \implies x \cup y \in X$ is false. For example, consider $ x = \{0\}, y = \{1\}, X = \{x, y\}$. So your reasoning is incorrect.